# How to check if Prolog going to return false?

Tags: prolog, return

Here is a portion of my code:

```
find_paths(A, B) :-
    path([A], B, Path, 0, Length),
    reverse(Path, DirectPath),
    printPath(DirectPath),
    writef(' with distance of %d\n', [Length]),
    ("IF PROLOG RETURN FALSE", write('End'); fail).
```

All the other parts are working fine except for when I wanted it to check if it returns false after retrieving all the data from database from looping.
"IF PROLOG RETURN FALSE" is where I wanted to insert the checking part but I don't know what to put. 
I tried the code below but it doesn't output the 'End' word.

```
find_paths(A, B) :-
    path([A], B, Path, 0, Length),
    reverse(Path, DirectPath),
    printPath(DirectPath),
    writef(' with distance of %d\n', [Length]),
    fail,
    write('End').
```

Comment: `fail` always fail. Prolog will never get to `write('End')` as its previous goal will never succeed.

Comment: What does "IF PROLOG RETURN FALSE" mean at that point in the clause? I assume you mean, "DO SOME OTHER QUERY (or QUERIES), and IF FAIL THEN write('End'), else just fail", and the entire clause fails, ultimately, in either case?

Comment: Why do you want your predicate to fail when it finds a path and ends?

Answer (score 0):

In order to print a message if a goal fails you can use something such as:

```
p:- goal, !.
p:- write('Failed').
```

Now, if you try to satisfy `p`, Prolog will use the first rule. If `goal` succeeds then the cut operator will remove previously created choice-points for goal `p` and it will not use the second rule. If `goal` fails, Prolog backtracks to satisfying `p`, uses the second clause and displays the message.

There *might* be one problem with this: because of the cut operator, `goal` is satisfied at most once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the same as Tudor proposed and allow backtracking with something like this:

```
p:- goal.
p:- not(goal), write('Failed').
```